# What is the difference between "dump data" and "dummy data" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, dump, dummy-data

What is the difference between "dump data" and "dummy data" in MySQL? And I want to make sure the purpose of dump data is to back up their data and dummy data is test functions. right?

Answer (score 0):

dump data is date dumped to an external file, for backup purposes.  dummy data is mock data, often used to test a database.  In production, e.g. you could use a tbale with towns in your country.  to test the application, you can use any town names, even town that do not exists.  That is dummy data.